# How to RDP to scale set when creating with defaults

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set

When I create a vm with defaults, it creates scale set without errors but it I do not seem to be able to RDP to the box using the NAT rule configuration.

```
New-AzVmss `
  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
  -Location "WestUS" `
  -VMScaleSetName "tktestScaleSet1" `
  -VirtualNetworkName "myVnet1" `
  -SubnetName "mySubnet" `
  -PublicIpAddressName "tktestvmssPIP1" `
  -LoadBalancerName "tktestLoadBalancer1" `
  -UpgradePolicyMode "Automatic" `
```

Even a simple default scaleset creation does not work

```
$vmssName = <VMSSNAME>
# Create credentials, I am using one way to create credentials, there are others as well. 
# Pick one that makes the most sense according to your use case.
$vmPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString <PASSWORD_HERE> -AsPlainText -Force
$vmCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(<USERNAME_HERE>, $vmPassword)

#Create a VMSS using the default settings
New-AzVmss -Credential $vmCred -VMScaleSetName $vmssName
```

It also seems to create a nat for 3389 and for 5985. Why is it creating nat for port 5985
[image]

This is not the behavior when I create the scaleset from portal for that it does not create the extra NAT rule for 5985 also I am able to RDP.

Is this a bug, or am I configuring it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It might be expected behavior. I also face the same scenario as you.

By default, that command `New-AzVmss` with default parameters does not create the health probe but creates a load balancing rule in the Azure portal. In this case, you could add a probe to enable the load balancing rules, then you could RDP to each of the VMSS instances.

[image]

You also see the [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/new-azvmss?view=azps-3.0.0#parameters). If no values are specified, ports 3389 and 5985 will be used for Windows VMS, and port 22 will be used for Linux VMs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From my experiment it looks like a bug with New-AzVmss. After running New-AzVmss I added an NSG to the Network and added inbound rule after that it started to work. It should have created a NSG when running New-AzVmss by default which did not happen but does from the portal.

> -SecurityGroupName
>       The name of the network security group to apply to this Scale Set. If no value is provided, a default network security group with the
>   same name as the Scale Set will be created and applied to the Scale
>   Set.